# Failing to set Action Bar icons in xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-icons

Whilst I can set Action Bar icons in my Java code, I'm unable to get them to display when I set them in my XML.  I'd prefer set them in XML.

Below are my two attempts to achieve the same thing - three icons on the Action Bar.  Could you explain why the second approach fails?

(Note, In my final version, I'm intending to keep two of the three in the overflow menu, I'm just trying to show all three during testing.)

This XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item   android:id="@+id/menuConfig"
                android:title="Configuration"
        />
        <item   android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
                android:title="About" 
        />
        <item   android:id="@+id/menuHelp"
                android:title="Help" 
        />
    </menu>
```

And this Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);

    MenuItem settings = menu.findItem(R.id.menuConfig);     
    settings.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);
    settings.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    MenuItem about = menu.findItem(R.id.menuAbout);     
    about.setIcon(R.drawable.about);
    about.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    MenuItem help = menu.findItem(R.id.menuHelp);       
    help.setIcon(R.drawable.help);
    help.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return true;
}
```

Produce this display:

[image]

Whereas, this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item   android:id="@+id/menuConfig"
            android:title="Configuration"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings"
            showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
    <item   android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
            android:title="About" 
            android:icon="@drawable/about"
            showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
    <item   android:id="@+id/menuHelp"
            android:title="Help" 
            android:icon="@drawable/help"
            showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
</menu>
```

And this Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Produce this display:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ok.

The overflow menu only shows text. The icons are only used when the Item is shown in the action bar as an action.

If you want to see the icons in the action bar you have to use

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

instead of

```
showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the items (or at least one of them) to be in the overflow menu.

I want Configure to be on the Action Bar and if I can't make it happen in XML then I have to deal with my code not working before API level 11.

Comment: you should call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); in onCreateOptionsMenu()

Comment: OK, but that doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: I did!  How could I miss that?  Thanks, that was all it was.